# taking input from a txt file and putting inside a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, parsing, parse-tree

I am using python to parse a txt file. My text file looks like this:
[image]

Text below here:

Master : 000000  Slave : 000001 000002
Master : 000003  Slave : 000004 000005
Master : 000006  Slave : 000007 000008
Master : 000010  Slave :
Master : 000012  Slave :
Master : 000014  Slave :
Master : 000016  Slave : 000017 000018
Master : 000020  Slave : 000021 000022
Master : 000024  Slave : 000025 000026
Master : 000028  Slave : 000029 000030
Master : 000032  Slave : 000033 000034
Master : 000036  Slave : 000037 000038

I want all these values inside a dictionary with master as keys and slaves as values.

> {master1: [slave1, slave2], master2: [slave1, slave2]}

KEYS        VALUES

00000       00001 , 00002

00003       00004 , 00005...

I am a python newbie. Please help.
Thank you

Comment: I see that `Slave`s kinda have multiple values, how do you want to store those? also please provide data in text format so that we can simply copy it and use for testing, also provide a [mre] of your attempt and the expected output

Comment: Hi I added the text as well. Thanks for pointing that out. For your question - slaves can be the keys as they are unique and the values can be the master then.

Comment: What about the lines where Slave has no (apparent) values?

Comment: we can simply ignore those and do not add them.

Comment: I understand but you should create data in format that makes the most sense (in usage and readability/understanding), so perhaps you want to store the slaves in a list? so sth like `dct = {master1: [slave1, slave2], master2: [slave1, slave2]}` (where `slave1` and `slave2` are the corresponding values obviously)?

Comment: yes thats what i actually want but shouldnt the keys be unique and in this case the slaves can have the same master. Wouldn't that be an issue?

Comment: but the key `master` will be unique IIUC, right? because `'Master'` values are unique?

Comment: yes true. I agree. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) module and regular expressions to find the master and slave values with a pattern, then simply get the groups from the pattern and add them to the dictionary accordingly:

```py
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'Master : (.*) Slave : (.*)')

file_name = 'myfile.txt'
dct = {}
with open(file_name, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        match = pattern.match(line.strip())
        if match:
            master, slave = match.groups()
            dct[master] = slave.split()

print(dct)
```

Output:

```py
{'000000': ['000001', '000002'],
 '000003': ['000004', '000005'],
 '000006': ['000007', '000008'],
 '000016': ['000017', '000018'],
 '000020': ['000021', '000022'],
 '000024': ['000025', '000026'],
 '000028': ['000029', '000030'],
 '000032': ['000033', '000034'],
 '000036': ['000037', '000038']}
```

Useful:

- [`re` module (built-in)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
- [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)

Comment: for me it prints an empty dictionary like this:
{ }

Comment: @user5440565 first of did you read the correct file and second, is your file exactly like the one you have provided in text format in your question? for example what happens if you copy-paste the supposed file contents from your question, put them in a file and read that file with this?

Comment: the answer you provided is absolutely correct. I have to find if there is something missing inside my code. I will get back to you as soon as I do.

Answer (score 0):

This would be my solution

```
dictionary = {}
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        slaves = line.split('Slave :')[1].strip()
        master = line.split('Slave :')[0].split('Master : ')[1].strip()
        list_of_slaves = slaves.split()
        dictionary[master] = list_of_slaves
```

It gave this as result

```
{'000000': ['000001', '000002'],
'000003': ['000004', '000005'],
'000006': ['000007', '000008'],
'000010': [],
'000012': [],
'000014': [],
'000016': ['000017', '000018'],
'000020': ['000021', '000022'],
'000024': ['000025', '000026'],
'000028': ['000029', '000030'],
'000032': ['000033', '000034'],
'000036': ['000037', '000038']}
```